# Finding average number of locations in each neighboring census tracts within a given distance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I have used the buffer and intersect tools to identify point locations within a certain distance of a census tract's boundaries.

I now want to calculate the average number of point locations in each of the neighboring census tract within a specified distance relative to a census tract of interest. I have included an image below for added clarity. In the census tract pictured, for example, I would like 7 different numbers that tell the sums of point locations in the seven neighboring census tracts within a specified distance.

I think that it might be possible to use the Spatial Join extract these averages in neighboring census tracts, but I am unsure of how exactly to specify it. In using the Spatial Join tool so far, I have only been able to calculate a sum of points within the entirety of each tract, which is not exactly my goal.

How would I specify this with the Spatial Join tool?

The layers used in my previous Spatial Join were a layer containing points within a distance of census tract boundaries and a layer of all census tracts. [image]

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/199974/115. Instead of asking the same question again the site protocols expect you to edit and improve your original question.  Please take the [Tour] to learn about the site and its protocols.